# Parsing a CSV file using Java and it stays in one line

Tags: java, csv, parsing

Each line in the CSV file looks like this:

Bob Billy, 97669013000,05/22/2020,@@\978334032=1003,disclosure,4869t,floodcert437289-17894729523.pdf,1003,disclosure,3247t,floodcert,9728453,472947361.

After the @@\ to .pdf should all have the commas in them. This shouldnt be parsed. Just the end to beginning with pipes or something. Then from the comma after the .pdf to flood cert, should also keep all the commas, and the 7 and 9 digit number stay parsed.

Im new to Java and would like to see how this is done. I have an idea but its very ugly.

Comment: You can't have unescaped commas in fields in a CSV file. You need to enclose fields that have commas in double quotes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit your question and add the expected output?

Something like:

```
Bob Billy
97669013000
05/22/2020
```

And so on? Also, do you want to retain the markers `@@\` etc, or drop them?